# Default timeout value of `requests.request()`?

Tags: python-requests, timeout

I don't find the default timeout value of `requests.request()`. Could anybody let me know what it is?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `timeout` argument is set to `None`.

[You can check there documentation:](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Session.request):

> ```
> request(method, url, params=None, data=None, headers=None,
> cookies=None, files=None, auth=None, timeout=None,
> allow_redirects=True, proxies=None, hooks=None, stream=None,
> verify=None, cert=None, json=None)
> ```

*[here](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts) is a bit more info about the `timeout` argument and how to use it.*